# Why is the error in this VBA code?

Tags: vba

When I run this VBA code, I get an error.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateBorder()
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.BorderAround
LineStyle:=xlDot, Weight:=xlThick, Color=RGB(255,0,0)
End Sub
```

The error seems to come up in the Sub CreateBorder() line. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues:

- you can't split a statement across two lines (unless you use a `_` at the end of the first line)
- parameters names need to be followed by `:=` (you use `Color=...`)

So it can be:

```
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.BorderAround LineStyle:=xlDot, Weight:=xlThick, Color:=RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

or

```
ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.BorderAround _
        LineStyle:=xlDot, Weight:=xlThick, Color:=RGB(255, 0, 0)
```